# Dynamic fromName using triggered data extension and AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to implement a dynamic sender profile (fromName and fromEmail) with a triggered send, using a data extension. The value of the fromName is in another Data Extension.

Here is what i have done:

1. I have activated Enhanced Sender profile, with help from SF support
2. I have run AMPscript to set the value of %%=v(@fromName)=%% through a lookup in the specific email HTML.
3. Setting the variable works fine. It returns the right fromName correctly.

For some reason this does not work in the dynamic sender profile, when adding %%=v(@fromName)=%%
Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

Create a content box and set an External Key e.g. SenderEmail.

Create a content box and set an External Key e.g. SendName

Inside your Content Boxes add your ampscript to set Email Name, Email address - though could be done as a simple `Set @FromName = 'something'`  or you could also do a lookup to a data extension.

In you sender profile, add the following to your From Name / From Email boxes `%%=ContentAreaByKey("SenderEmail")=%%`

Comment: Please also note the reason the variable does not fill when set in the email is that AMPscript processes the From Name/Email fields prior to the email, unlike the subject and preheader - which can be set in the email.  This is why you need to put the full script either inside the sender profile field or into a content area as @iManage has suggested.